# Can't scrape title

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I've successfully gathered all the data I wanted from a page, but I can't figure out why I am not able to extract the title or stock symbol from the same age. None of what I've tried works.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

The initial code I had written did not work well and someone from this site helped with it already. I know the table name is right, but I can't seem to figure out why it does not work. Just for reference what I am trying to get is the Ticker symbol under the chart and the name of the company.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class WebScrape {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ticker: ");
        String userInput = scanner.next();
        final String url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + userInput;

        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element row : document.select("table.fullview-title tr")) {
                if ( !row.select("td.fullview-title:nth-of-
                        type(2)").text().contentEquals("")) {
                        String data = row.select("td.fullview-title:nth-of-
                                type(2)").text();
                                dataArray.add(data);
            }

            System.out.println(dataArray);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors and I can easily connect to the url, but the code just returns an empty value.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It's not clear what specifically you're trying to get. The ticker is in a link with the id `ticker`, can't be that hard. Don't know what you mean by "title" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change selectors.

"table.fullview-title tr" -> "table.fullview-title tr td"

"td.fullview-title:nth-of-type(2)" -> "a.fullview-ticker"

I hope this helps:

```
    public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//  Simplification:
//        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//        System.out.println("Ticker: ");
//        String userInput = scanner.next();
//        final String url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + userInput;
        final String url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=LCI";

        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element row : document.select("table.fullview-title tr td")) {
                if (!row.select("a.fullview-ticker").text().contentEquals("")) {
                    String data = row.select("a.fullview-ticker").text();
                    dataArray.add(data);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(dataArray);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ouput:

```
[LCI]
```

Comment: Done. Thanks for review.

Comment: Mark it as answer please :)